# How to dynamically create a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At first I am using a Date Picker. From that Date Picker, I am getting a Date value.
Then, from a Url I am getting another JSON Value. This is working fine. Once I have these values, I want to show them in a table format.
So far, I am not able to show my data in the Table format.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
        onSelect: function() { 
            var d = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
            //alert("date!!!!" + date);
            $(".current" ).empty();
            $(".current" ).append("<table border='0'>");
            $(".current" ).append("<tr>");
            $(".current" ).append("<th>Time</th>");
            $(".current").append("   "); 
            $(".current").append("<th>EventName</th>");
            $(".current").append("   "); 
            $(".current").append("<th>EventDescription</th>");
            $(".current").append("   "); 
            $(".current").append("<th>Image</th>");
            $(".current" ).append("</tr>");

            $.getJSON('http://xx:80/xxx/xxx/xx/xx/SampleWork_SA/?xx=xx&source=xx&cmpntname=x', function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    if (d === val.Date) {
                        var row = $("<tr><td>" + val.Time +"  " + "</td><td>"+"  " + val.EventName +"  " + "</td><td>"+"  " + val.EventDescription +" " + '<img class="meeting" src="http://localhost:10039' + val.Image + '" alt="" />' +"</td></tr>");
                        $(".current").append("</table>");
                        $(".current").append(row);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you appending a string of whitespace?

Comment: Instead of using multiple `append`s you should do it in one go. Either as a single string, or by setting a variable with the html. The way you're doing it is pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.append()` its immediately added to DOM hence you must be generating invalid HTML.

So Solution is to generate string once the append like

```
var html = "";
html += "<table border='0'>";
html += "<tr>";
html += "<th>Time</th>";
html += "<th>EventName</th>";
html += "<th>EventDescription</th>";
html += "<th>Image</th>";
html += "</tr>";

$.getJSON('http://xx:80/xxx/xxx/xx/xx/SampleWork_SA/?xx=xx&source=xx&cmpntname=x', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if (d === val.Date) {
            var row = $("<tr><td>" + val.Time +"  " + "</td><td>"+"  " + val.EventName +"  " + "</td><td>"+"  " + val.EventDescription +" " + '<img class="meeting" src="http://localhost:10039' + val.Image + '" alt="" />' +"</td></tr>");
            html += row;
        }
    });
    html += "</table>";
    $( ".current" ).html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .html() instead of .append() on these lines

```
$(".current" ).append("</table>");
$( ".current" ).append(row);
```

This would replace the html of the element with your table specs in the row var.

Documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot about this code that I'd clean up, but the thing that sticks out to me is `$(".current").append("</table>");`

I think you'll want to put that after your `$.each` has finished up. Otherwise you're closing your table too early.